# mod_rewrite rule to drop the string with m=1 from the URL regardless of its location?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to create a mod_rewrite rule that can change this:

`exampledomain/blog/2013/10/?view=flipcard&m=1&_escaped_fragment_=`

To this:

`exampledomain/blog/2013/10/`

And this:

`exampledomain/blog/review-of-items/?view=timeslide&m=1`

To this:

`exampledomain/blog/review-of-items/`

Basically to check inside the final string for `m=1` and drop that final string only regardless of the number of slashes beforehand?

And please note we are not dropping m=1 only like in some other questions, we would like to get rid of the entire string i.e. 
`?view=flipcard&m=1&_escaped_fragment_=`
or
`?view=timeslide&m=1`

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? if "m=1" is part of the url you want to remove everything starting from the "?" and retain the rest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=302]
```

`(^|&)m=1(&|$)` regex is to make sure `m=1` is matched anywhere in query string.

Comment: Thank you for the unbelievable speed! This was my first question on stackoverflow and I am completely blown away! Can I follow up and ask what element/section in the Rule is actually eliminating the string? and how was it specified in the first place? I have difficulty seeing through the rewrite codes as I am new to it and can't find a resource that breaks it down in an easy way. Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=1(&|$) [NC]` is matching `m=1` in the query string. Each query parameter can be preceded or followed by `&` that's why `(^|&)m=1(&|$)` regex is used. Then `%{REQUEST_URI}?` in target URI is stripping all the query string.